# Generalized singular numbers and the Haagerup $L^p$ spaces

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, real-analysis, oa.operator-algebras, operator-theory

Let $M$ be a semi-finite von Neumann algebra with a trace $\tau$.Let $S(M)$ be the algebra of all affiliated operators measurable with respect to $M$.
 The $L^p$ norm on $M$ is given by
\begin{equation}
\|a\|^p_{L^p(M)}=\tau(|a|^p),\quad a\in S(M).
\end{equation}
Now, there is a notion of the generalised singular values for $a\in S(M)$
\begin{equation}
\mu_t(a)=\inf\{s\geq 0\colon \tau(E_{(s,+\infty)}(|A|)\leq t\},
\end{equation}
where $E_{(s,+\infty)}(|A|)$ is the spectral projection of the modulus of $A$.
It has been shown In F. Thierry and H. Kosaki. Generalized s-numbers of τ-measurable operators. Pacific J. Math., 123(2):269–300, 1986. Corollary 2.8
\begin{equation}
\|a\|_{L^p(M)}
=\left(\tau(|a|^p\right)^{\frac1p}=\\
\left(
\int\limits^{+\infty}_0
\mu_t(a)^p\,dt
\right)^{\frac1p}\quad 0<p<+\infty.
\end{equation}
Now, we are almost ready to formulate the question.
Let $M$ be an arbitrary von Neumann algebra with a normal faithful weight $\varphi_0$. Let $L^1(M)$ be the Haagerup $L^1$-space.  To the best of my understanding, $L^1(M)$ is the space of all operators $a$ which are Radon-Nykodime derivative of a weight $\varphi$ with respect to a chosen and fixed weight $\varphi_0$. Then its $L^1$-norm $\|a\|_{L^1(M)}=\varphi(1)$.
Now, regarding the $\mu_t(a)$ for an operator $a$ from general von Neumann algebra. The cross-product $R(M,\sigma^{\varphi_0})$ of $M$ with respect to the modular automorphism group $\sigma^{\varphi_0}$ has always a semi-finite trace $\tau$. Then using the definition for $\mu_t(a)$ above it has been shown in http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0022123684900557  Lemma B that
\begin{equation}
\mu_t(a)=\frac1{t}\|a\|_{L^1(M)},
\end{equation}
here $\mu_t(a)$ is computed with respect to the trace on $R(M,\sigma^{\varphi_0})$. Then one should get
\begin{equation}
\|a\|_{L^1(M)}=\int\limits^{+\infty}_0 \mu_t(a)dt=\|a\|_{L^1(M)}\int\limits^{+\infty}_0\frac{dt}{t}.
\end{equation}
Since the integral is divergent, we get absurd.
I have to be wrong somewhere. Could anyone help me understand my mistake? I might suggest that the different traces are used. Thanks a lot.

Comment: In your formulas μ_t is taken with respect to two different traces: the trace τ on M and the newly constructed trace on the Takesaki dual R(M,σ).  The latter trace equals ∞ when restricted to M, consistent with your last formula.  This explains the apparent discrepancy.

Comment: @DmitriPavlov Do I get it right then that $\tau(|a|^p)=\int\limits^{+\infty}_0 \mu_t(a)^p\,dt$ for the trace  $\tau$ on the crossed-product $R(M,\sigma)$? What reference one might give up to a ""statement x on page y in work z"?

Comment: The canonical trace τ on the Takesaki dual R(M,σ) is a faithful semifinite trace, hence the cited result by Fack and Kosaki is applicable.  The relevant integral is infinite, thus the element a does not belong to L^1(R(M,σ),τ).

Comment: @DmitriPavlov: Let ${\mathrm Tr}$ be the trace on Haagerup's $L^1(M)$ and $\tau$ be the canonical trace on the crossed-product $R(M,\sigma)$. Is the cited result by Fack and Kosaki still holds for $Tr$? In other words, does this formula hold true $\|a\|_{L^1(M)}=\int\limits^{+\infty}_0 \mu_t(a)\,dt$, where $\mu_t(a)$ is taken with respect to the trace ${\mathrm Tr}$ on $L^1(M)$?

Comment: I don't think I understand your question: in order to apply the Fack-Kosaki theorem you need a trace on a von Neumann algebra.  Tr is not such a trace because L^1(M) is not a von Neumann algebra.  On the other hand, τ is such a trace and the Fack-Kosaki theorem correctly computes the answer for the case of τ, i.e., ∞.

Comment: @DmitriPavlov It has been shown by Haagerup that for semifinite von Neumann algebra $M$ its cross-product $R(M,\sigma)=M\otimes U(\mathbb{R})$, where $U(\mathbb{R})$ is the convolution algebra.  How the trace  $\tau$ on $R(M,\sigma)$ simplifies for the semi-finite case?